# Cocoa: Global Shortcuts in Lion

Tags: cocoa, osx-lion, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been looking for a way to implement a global shortcut for my app that would work like shortcut recorder. The problem is I haven't found one that works with the current version of xcode, every single one I've found throws an error in xcode about legacy stuff. The only one i've found that is any good in Lion is DDHotKey, which does exactly what I want, but it has the downside that the user doesn't record the shortcut in a nifty smart textfield sort of thing, its a preset shortcut.

Can anyone tell me how to add a smart textfield to DDHotKet, or a fix for SR in Lion? It seems that for ShortcutRecorder the specific problem has to do with the actual textfield in IB using old plug-ins, so I can't use the text field (which is what I really want). I've looked up a whole bunch of different frameworks but they all have outdated stuff. To be honest even if I found a fix for running SR I still have no idea what to do since it seems to be waaay more complicated than all the others i've found.

Answer (score 0):

This fork of ShortcutRecorder builds in Xcode 4:

https://github.com/youknowone/shortcutrecorder

It also has a nice demo project that shows how to use the API.